# Unresolved directive error when using the Asciidoctor Maven plugin to publish the API documentation in HTML format

Tags: spring, maven, asciidoc

I have success use Spring RestDocs to write a test and generated snippets.

When I use the `Asciidoctor Maven plugin` to publish the API documentation in HTML format, the HTML doc is generated.

However, the HTML shows following error. It seems that my include does not function as expected. I wonder what could be wrong.

> Unresolved directive in api-guide.adoc -
>   include::/opt/caweb/thoughtworks/go-agent/pipelines/xxx_Build/xxx-source/target/generated-snippets/creating-grouping/curl-request.adoc[]

Here is asciidoctor-maven-plugin and maven-resources-plugin sections of **POM.xml**:

```
<plugin> 
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>

                    <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                        <attributes>
                            <snippets>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippets>
                        </attributes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-docs</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the include section of my api-guide.adoc:

```
include::{snippets}/create-grouping/curl-request.adoc[]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try running maven clean and maven package.

Answer (score 0):

Are you configuring your sure plugin to include your documentation files ??

[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/docs/src/docs/asciidoc/getting-started.adoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEMxW.jpg)

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEMxW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the phase on asciidoctor from **prepare-package** to **package**